# Existence of generalized eigenvector

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given a finite dimensional vector space $V$ over $\mathbb{C}$ and a linear transformation $L:V \to V $, we know that eigenvalues exist, since the characteristic equation will be a polynomial with complex coefficients, which we know has roots. However, when do generalized eigenvectors exist?

For example, if $A$ is a real matrix, and we find that it doesn't have linearly independent eigenvectors, does it necessarily have generalized eigenvectors? It seems like the purpose of generalized eigenvectors is to find a way around things like multiplicities and linearly dependencies, but how do we know they exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that an eigenvector is in particular a generalized eigenvector. So, existence of eigenvalues implies existence of eigenvector, which in turn implies existence of generalized eigenvector.

**Added Remarks about generalised eigenvectors**

And, as for the purpose of generalised eigenvectors, here's a brief overview: the purpose is to get as close to diagonalizability as possible. If $T: V \to V$ has the distinct eigenvalues $\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_r$, and is diagonalizable, our vector space has a nice direct sum decomposition:
\begin{equation}
V = \bigoplus_{i=1}^r E_{\lambda_i},
\end{equation}
where $E_{\lambda_i} = \ker (T- \lambda_i I)$ is the eigenspace. But, when $T$ is not diagonalizable, what this means is atleast one of the eigenspaces is not "big enough" or said differently, there aren't enough eigenvectors to span $V$. So, naturally, we might be led to seek a generalization of $E_{\lambda_i}$, to a "bigger space", $G_{\lambda_i}$ which contains $E_{\lambda_i}$, and such that we have a direct sum decomposition of the vector space:
\begin{equation}
V = \bigoplus_{i=1}^r G_{\lambda_i}.
\end{equation}

It turns out that $G_{\lambda_i} = \bigcup \limits_{q=1}^{\infty} \ker(T-\lambda_i I)^q$, satisfies this property, and this leads to the theory of Jordan Canonical Forms for linear maps whose characteristic polynomials split.